# AWS: Not able to retrieve mail logs using putty. Getting permission denied error

Tags: email, logging, amazon-web-services

I am working on getting the error logs for mail.

The path .. /var/logs/ -> mail

But view the file i am getting permission denied error. please help me to know how to retrieve the mail logs.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type 'sudo' before your cat or less command. You need to elevate to root permissions.

```
sudo less /var/log/maillog
```